# PHP Двойные и одинарные кавычки

Tags: php, mysql

Всем доброго дня. Совсем запутался в кавычках:

```
$a=$_GET['a'];
$b=$_GET['b'];
$search_query = "SELECT *  FROM $a WHERE city='$b'";
$query = mysql_query($search_query);
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
{
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($query);
do{
$array1.="<tr><td>".$myrow['name']."</tr></td>";
}
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($query));}
echo json_encode(array("table"=>$array1,"name"=>$array2));
```

Если код оставить так `$array1.="<tr><td>".$myrow['name']."</tr></td>";`, то результат выдаст: `{"table":"Holiday INN<\/tr><\/td>Tramp<\/tr><\/td>","name":"Holiday INNTramp"}` 
Почему выдает </tr></td>, а не `<tr><td>Holiday INN</tr></td>`?

Правильно ли расставлены кавычки в коде:?

```
$a=$_GET['a'];
$b=$_GET['b'];
$search_query = "SELECT *  FROM $a WHERE city='$b'";
```

Comment: Да, кавычки расставлены правильно (хоть по феншую, ваш код надо переписать так, чтобы кавычки использовались только в одном месте - там где SQL-запрос, и были бы они одинарными)

Comment: Не по существу вопроса - но у вас открывающему тегу <td> соответствует закрывающий </tr> и наоборот. Кроме того, включение данных из GET непосредственно в тело запроса - самая плохая практика, какую только можно использовать (задумайтесь. что будет, если в $_GET['b'] придет значение `0'; DROP TABLE cities;--` или что-то в этом роде).

Comment: Да, с тегами попутал малец, но это при выводе увидел. По поводу включения переменной в тело запроса: имеется в виду, что надо проверить условием существует ли переменная и не содержит ли она отличное от букв? Или непосредственно в скрипте перед отправкой запроса надо это все проверять, ввел ли пользователь в поле input буквы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выдает `<\/tr><\/td>` потому, что `json_encode` экранирует символ `/` в полном соответствии с [RFC 7159](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc7159.html)

Чтобы этого избежать, используйте его так

```
json_encode(array("table"=>$array1,"name"=>$array2), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: Благодарствую..

Comment: @Шура на этом ресурсе лучшая благодарность расположена слева от ответа ;)

Answer (score -1):

Вообще то у вас ошибка html синтаксиса внимательно посмотрите на пример

```
$array1.="<tr><td>".$myrow['name']."</tr></td>";
```

я вижу ошибку в закрывающих тегах

```
  $array1.="<tr><td>".$myrow['name']."</td></tr>";
```

Ответ: у вас кавычки правильно расставлены.

По поводу ковычек - если речь идет о производительности то использование одинарных ковычек намного производительнее, поскольку в двойных идет поиск переменных